# NSUInteger written into NSData (Objective-c) cannot be converted as integer (Java)

Tags: java, objective-c, arrays

I'm trying to read a binary file written in Objective-C like this :

```
u_int32_t test = 71508;

NSMutableData * outputData = [ [ NSData dataWithBytes:&test length:sizeof( u_int32_t ) ] mutableCopy ];

// Saves the data
...

// Then reading the value works fine
u_int32_t test;
[ self getBytes:&test length:sizeof( u_int32_t ) ];
```

Then I'm trying to read the int in Java :

```
// Read the file
...
Bytes ObjCBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray( );
...

// Try to convert my Objective-C byte array to an int :
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( 4 );
buffer.put( ObjCBytes );
buffer.flip( );
int ObjCInt = buffer.getInt( );
```

But I don't have the same result!

So, I decided to do the same in Java :

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( 4 );
buffer.putInt( 71508 );
bytes javaBytes = buffer.array( );
```

It seems that the two byte arrays are inverted :

*ObjCBytes : {84, 23, 1, 0}*

*javaBytes : {0, 1, 23, 84}*

The behavior is the same regardless of the integer value.

Sorry : I'm newbie ...
I believe that the reason is that Java has no unsigned int ?

I tried a lot of answers, but I have not found the solution.

How can I convert my byte array to an integer **regardless of the language used to write it**?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You could just reverse the byte array on one side or the other.

Comment: @Avi, yes if I consider that the byte array was written if Objective-C. I don't want to do that.

Comment: Reverse it on the ObjC side.  If you also need to read it back in ObjC, you'll know that it was reversed, so you reverse it again.

Comment: @Avi, Thank you but I think that your solution is "a band-aid on a wooden leg". My app will work on Android and Objective-C. So I want to read or write my int regardless of the language used.

Comment: You'll have to choose another method of serialization if you don't want to do the easy thing.  Byte ordering is an old problem, and every implementation needs to deal with it at some point.  Look at the C `hton*` functions, for example.

Comment: @Avi, thanks for your help. I decided to use the BIG_ENDIAN order in Objective-C (CFSwapInt32BigToHost / CFSwapInt32HostToBig) like Java does. That works!

Comment: That's basically what I recommended.  Good choice :)

Comment: Thank you you helped me to understand. So the solution is that I must respect the network byte order which is BIG ENDIAN. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Well, Java uses big endian, while ObjC uses the native ordering (which is little-endian for both x86 and ARM, though ARM can be switched, IIRC).  The only requirement for your code is to be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, NSData use the little_endian byte order by default while Java use big_endian byte order.

[More information on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

I decided to convert my NSData to big_endian so it can be read in Java:

```
NSUInteger    test = 71508;

// Java compatibility
u_int32_t bigEndianTest = CFSwapInt32BigToHost( test );

// Writes the value
NSMutableData * outputData = [ [ NSData dataWithBytes:&bigEndianTest length:saltSize ] mutableCopy ];
```

As needed, the reverse is possible (Java => Little Endian => Objective-C)